# Selenium click like on twitter

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What is the most recent and up to date way to click "like" on a tweet using selenium?

From the css, it looks like I need to click on this:

```
<div aria-haspopup="false" aria-label="131310 Likes. Like" role="button" data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1777fci r-11cpok1 r-1ny4l3l r-bztko3 r-lrvibr" data-testid="like">
```

That is found on a profile page.  My goal isn't to exactly like a tweet on a profile page but If I can figure this out, I'll be able to figure out what I actually want to do.

I have tried a bunch of ways but here are my most recent:

`like_btn = (By.XPATH, ("//div[@data-testid='like', @class='css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1777fci r-11cpok1 r-1ny4l3l r-bztko3 r-lrvibr']"))`

`like_btn = (By.XPATH, ("//div[@data-testid='like'"))`

copy of Xpath:

```
like_btn = (By.XPATH, ("//*[@id='react-root']/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div"))
```

Copy of full xpath:

```
like_btn = (By.XPATH, ("/html/body/div/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div"))
```

The method then uses:

```
def like_user_tweets(self, user_tweets=UserStatuses.like_btn):
    self.like_btn.click()
```

It looks like twitter recently revamped everything because even github code from only a year or less ago uses "HeartAnimation" class to find the like button but that doesn't seem to exist anymore.

The error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'`

It is a button so shouldn't it be able to click?

How can I click the like/favorite button?

Comment: _It is a button so shouldn’t it be able to click?_ Look at the error though, that’s not the issue. As far as I can tell all you need to do is find the appropriate xpath for the element. It’s the exact same process as finding the xpath for any element, there doesn’t seem to be any aspect to Twitter that is completely different from most cases.

Comment: So shouldn't my copy of either of the Xpath or full Xpath be working? Anything you can see wrong with my syntax?

Comment: To clarify my xpath .. that is the actual copypasta directly from chromes inspect

Comment: Have you checked that your element you want to click is in an iframe? If it's that, you have to switch to that iframe to find that button.

Comment: @MinhDao Searched through the inspect for "iframe" and there is none that poopped upa

Comment: Does that element need be waited to show up? If that's so, a fluent wait will help you out.

Comment: I run a `time.sleep(2)` before  I run the click attempt.  would this be impacting it ?

Comment: @uno Unlikely, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <div aria-label="394 Likes. Like" role="button" tabindex="0" 
data-testid="like">...</div> is not clickable at point (539, 10). 

Other element would receive the click: <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1habvwh">...</div>
```

Solution:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
infoq_url = 'https://twitter.com/infoqchina'
browser.get(infoq_url)
sleep(2)

like_buttons = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="like"]') 
like_btn = like_buttons[0]
like_svg = like_btn.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "svg")
like_svg.click()
```

Reference:

```
btn_parent = btn.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")  # find parent element.
```